# Screen resolution messes up when logging in

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, monitor

Recently i bought a new monitor and connected it to my laptop. When I was using windows everything in terms of resolution was fine but when i switch to Ubuntu, my log in screen is zoomed in. When i press enter, i can see only the purple color and have to type in my password without seeing it on screen. The problem is, it doesn't only happen when I am logging in with my laptop connected to monitor, but also when I use laptop separately.
I tried typing in

```
xrandr --auto
```

in terminal, but it didn't help.
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First, find out what your monitor is detected by Ubuntu. Open up a terminal, type this command to show your display details:

```
xrandr -q
```

You only have two monitors(one is the laptop screen, other is your external monitor) you will see a line which contains information about the monitors.

In the first line, the first word will be the monitor type. For, a convenience I assume it is detected as DVI-0.
Now, open up a terminal and create a file using the command

```
nano lightdmxrandr.sh
```

Paste the following contents in the file

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output <DVI-0> --primary --mode <1440x900>
```

Replace the value  with the monitor type(detected in `xrandr -q`)

Make the script executable:

```
chmod a+rx lightdmxrandr.sh
```

Now run it:

```
./lightdmxrandr.sh

(If your screen automatically auto-corrects after login you probably won't see a difference so you may want to use a test resolution that is different but you know works while testing)
```

Now, the script needs to be run in `lightdm`, navigate to the correct folder:

```
cd /etc/lightdm
```

Open up the lightdm conf file:

```
sudo gedit lightdm.conf
```

Go to the end of the file and paste the line

```
display-setup-script=/home/<username>/lightdmxrandr.sh
```

Replace  with your username
Finally, reboot and that should set the correct resolution on your `lightdm` login screen.

Comment: Nah it's still messed up, but thanks for the effort. It could be because at final step when I saved the lightdm.conf file, it said "Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit -encoding not supported"

Comment: @choondrise okay. in the place of second last command(Open up the lightdm conf file), replace it with `sudo nano lightdm.conf` ,go to the end of the file and paste the line display-setup-script=/home/<username>/lightdmxrandr.sh. now, press Ctrl x and then y and press Enter

Comment: The output is still the same... Maybe because I had to create /etc/lightdm directory myself and before I did it there was lighttpd directory in it?

Comment: `lightdm` and `lighthttpd` are very different packages. `lightdm` is  the display manager running in Ubuntu and `lighttpd` is an open-source web server

Comment: Oh, my bad. So any idea what to do if the last tip doesn't help either?

Comment: What is you your ubuntu version

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS